# Java: Return value to shell script from jar

Tags: java, shell

In cluster direcory home/ I locate
app.jar
and run_app.sh

Java application, packed in app.jar, return value as following:

```
 System.exit(1);
```

Script in run_app.sh:

```
   typeset -i result
   result=$(java -jar tfs.jar -cp app/build/classes/java/main com.example.tfs.Application)
   echo ${result}
```

Application starts successfully by this script. But echo always return 0.

I tried to pass the return value as property:

```
System.setProperty("java.return.value", String.valueOf(1));
```

Then in shell:

```
 typeset -i result
 java -jar tfs.jar -cp tfs/build/classes/java/main com.example.tfs.TfsApplication
 export java.return.value=${result}
 echo ${result}
```

In this case echo show nothing, but also I receive the error

```
'export java.return.value=': not a valid identificator
```

Comment: What you _return_ goes in `$?`. What `$(...)` captures is stdout, not $?. And when you use `typeset -i` you're making non-numeric data be ignored/misinterpreted.

Comment: That is all to say, you want `java -jar tfs.jar -cp tfs/build/classes/java/main com.example.tfs.TfsApplication; result=$?`

Comment: I expected java -jar tfs.jar ..... return  1. So I expected result=1

Comment: Again, the exit status of the last thing run goes in `$?`. Therefore, if you never run `result=$?`, the 1 never gets into `result`. `$()` doesn't use/check/modify/otherwise have anything to do with exit status at all.

Comment: (And Java properties are a one-way street; they go into the JVM, but they don't come out of it; their values are destroyed when the JVM exits).

Comment: *I expected java -jar tfs.jar ..... return 1.* Why so - did you write `System.exit(1)` at the end of `main`? If you had done, then you can capture `$?` and it should be 1

Comment: @g00se, yes, the OP says they did indeed write `System.exit(1)`, but they were trying to capture the resulting exit status with a command substitution instead of referring to `$?`.